# Display extra form fields if dropdown is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make two extra form fields appear if the user selects `'Yes'` from a dropdown. If the user does not select `'Yes'` from the dropdown, then the two extra fields are not required and are disabled, however if `'Yes'` is selected these fields *must* be filled in before form submission. I have this so far, however it's not working. If anyone could point out the issue it would be greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="action.php">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Defect?</label>
    <select onclick='checkIfYes()' class="select form-control" id="defect" name="defect">
      <option id="No" value="No">No</option>
      <option id="Yes" value="Yes">Yes</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div id="extra" name="extra" style="display: none">

    <label class="control-label" for="desc">Description</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="desc" name="desc" required disabled>

    <label class="control-label" for="auth_by">Authorised By</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="auth_by" name="auth_by" required disabled>

  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-info" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit">Submit
    </button>
  </div>

</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function checkIfYes() {
  if (document.getElementById('defect').value == 'Yes') {
    document.getElementById('extra').style.display = '';
    document.getElementById('auth_by').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('desc').disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('extra').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sinesine/z6Lm1m5x/15/)**

Comment: When l run this fiddle l get checkIfYes is not defined. checkIfYes needs to be defined before the html. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z6Lm1m5x/16/

Comment: @MattLaza - The fields now display if yes is selected but it doesn't let you submit the form if no is selected.

Comment: Sorry l cant seem to replicate that in the fiddle. Both yes and no submit the form. It redirects in the fiddle. Check to see if any additional javascripts errors are being thrown?

Comment: @MattLaza No problem it was something on my end, works now. If you would like to create an answer and I will mark as correct. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checkIfYes needs to be defined before the HTML that references it.

I would also recommend changing the select onclick event to onchange so that it only gets called when the user actually changes he value

See updated fiddle : [Updated Fiddle](http://%20jsfiddle.net/z6Lm1m5x/16)

```html
<script>      
  function checkIfYes() {
      if (document.getElementById('defect').value == 'Yes') {
        document.getElementById('extra').style.display = '';
        document.getElementById('auth_by').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('desc').disabled = false;
      } else {
        document.getElementById('extra').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
</script>
<form id="form" method="post" action="action.php">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Defect?</label>
    <select onchange='checkIfYes()' class="select form-control" id="defect" name="defect">
      <option id="No" value="No">No</option>
      <option id="Yes" value="Yes">Yes</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div id="extra" name="extra" style="display: none">

    <label class="control-label" for="desc">Description</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="desc" name="desc" required disabled>

    <label class="control-label" for="auth_by">Authorised By</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="auth_by" name="auth_by" required disabled>

  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-info" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit">Submit
    </button>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: **Correction:** It does not necessarly need to be defined before the HTML!

Comment: Would it be in this case then because the function may not have been declared within script tags?

Comment: Just try it! It's not important whether it's it defined before or after!